# Android get Approximate Location without GPS & Network Provider ON

Tags: android, gps, google-geocoder, locationlistener

I have tried to get current location without using GPS & Network Provider settings in mobile. I could not get the location. even, I have tried using Mobile Data Internet and WiFi Internet. could not get the location approximately at least.

IF Anyway is there to get at least approximate location of device programmatic ally. 
Any possible way is there using mobile tower location getting in Android Programmatically /  or Any Other way is there to get location without Turn On GPS and Network Provider .

Thanks Advance

Comment: i recommend you give this library a try -> https://github.com/yayaa/LocationManager

Comment: u gat get location. But you should either use network provider(not internet) or GPS.

Comment: If you are ok with that. i can explain how to do that.

Comment: i have tried Google Pay Services library. But, that one also, if enabled GPS state, latitude and longitude will return. otherwise, its saying No location to return for getLastLocation().